# "npm update -g create-react-app" does not update the create-react-app as it is supposed to do

Tags: node.js, npm, create-react-app

```
$ npm install -g create-react-app@1.5.2
```

I used this command installed the create-react-app before.

```
$ create-react-app --version
1.5.2
```

Now, I wanted to update create-react-app version

I run

```
$ npm update -g create-react-app
```

Nothing happened.

```
$ create-react-app --version
1.5.2
```

The version is still 1.5.2.

Is that because when I installed create-react-app, I specified the version to be 1.5.2, so the version is locked? If so, how do I make the change so I can update create-react-app?

Comment: `npm install -g create-react-app`

Comment: you should probably be using npx for create-react-app. Npx is generally used for functionality instead of libraries i.e. when you want npm to DO something for you instead of download something for you (or update all your dependencies when you didn't ask it too -classic npm)                                                                    ALSO: switch to yarn

Comment: Thanks, Aluan, "npm install -g create-react-app" works. But why "npm update -g create-react-app" does not work? such as "npm update -g browser-sync" was working fine.